# Determine which MySQL configuration file is being used

Tags: mysql, configuration

Is there a command to determine which configuration file MySQL 5.0 is currently using?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you are on Linux, then start the 'mysqld' with `strace`, for eg  `strace ./mysqld`.

Among all the other system calls, you will find something like:

```
stat64("/etc/my.cnf", 0xbfa3d7fc)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4227, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
```

So, as you can see..it lists the .cnf files, that it attempts to use and finally uses.

Comment: And how to do that on a running system without messing up anything?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov You should run `ps auxf` and find the command executed for MySQL. Typically it look like something such as `mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql ...` (note the ... just means that there may be more flags in the command but I won't list all of it) Once you've found it, copy the whole thing and then shutdown MySQL. If you're on Linux it is `/etc/init.d/mysqld stop` or `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`. Then run `strace` with the mysql command you copied. So it would look like so: `strace mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql`

Comment: I don't have the `open(...` line. Instead I have 4 lines that end with  `= -1 Err#2`. How do you I know now which file is loaded?

Comment: fwiiw, on a Mac you can use dtruss instead of strace: `sudo dtruss mysqld 2>&1|grep my.cnf`
@mgPePe, that output likely means that none of the files was found so none were opened.

Answer (score 342):

Taken from the fantastic "High Performance MySQL" O'Reilly book:

```
$ which mysqld
/usr/sbin/mysqld

$ /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: And I assume the last file listed wins?

Comment: that's odd.. I checked each and everyone of those and they're all empty (on my mac).. any idea why?

Comment: This doesn't give the loaded configuration. rather possible custom configurations that might be loaded

Comment: I don't think this will list files specified by `!includedir`. I'm trying to figure out why the `!includedir` directive in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file is not working.

Comment: @ButtleButkus I had a similar issue and it was because there was an extra line after !includedir. Removing that line helped.

Comment: Why would you need to call `mysqld` with the full path?!

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows. You need this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17554146/491553

Comment: I just tried to vote up this answer again 2 years after the first time.. it's good to know that I still have the good habit of not settling for the accepted answer and keep reading a little more xD

Answer (score 83):

If you run `mysql --verbose --help | less` it will tell you about line 11 which `.cnf` files it will look for.

You can also do `mysql --print-defaults` to show you how the configuration values it will use for the client session in configuration file [client]. This can also be useful in identifying just which config file it is loading.

For server configuration session [mysqld] you can use:

```
mysqld --print-defaults
```

Comment: +1 because this is the mysql recommended way to do this. For windows one simple way is to dump the output to a file if you like to analyze the content.

Comment: On windows, it told me a list of locations but not the right one, that instead i manage to find with mysql workbench (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17953456/1504300).

Comment: Not sure it should matter, but you might want to use `mysqld` instead of `mysql`

Comment: And still in Windows I experience that the my.ini is read from the ProgramData directory, and this does not show in the answer suggested here.

Comment: Upvoted for `mysqld --print-defaults`, it gave me exactly what I wanted when I googled this question.

Answer (score 32):

I am on Windows and I have installed the most recent version of MySQL community 5.6

What I did to see what configuration file uses was to go to Administrative Tools > Services > MySQL56 > Right click > Properties and check the path to executable:

"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56

Comment: This works for MySQL 5.7 as well.  It's in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini` by default.

Answer (score 23):

An alternative is to use

```
mysqladmin variables
```

Comment: It doesn't actually say where the cnf file is in my variables. I'm currently running MySQL 5.5.20. However, I can say that once upon a time this did work as I have seen it previously in the variables. Perhaps something changed since moving to 5.5.

Answer (score 15):

mysqld --help --verbose is dangerous. You can easily overwrite pidfile for running instance! use it with --pid-file=XYZ

Oh, and you can't really use it if you have more than 1 instance running. It will only show you default value.

Really good article about it:

[How to find MySQL configuration file?](http://web.archive.org/web/20161017030124/https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/)

Answer (score 11):

Just did a quick test on ubuntu:

- installed mysql-server, which created /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"

110112 13:35:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

- created /etc/my.cnf and /usr/etc/my.cnf, each with a different port number
- restarted mysql - it was using the port number set in /usr/etc/my.cnf

Also meanwhile found the --defaults-file option to the mysqld.  If you specify a config file there, only that one will be used, regardless of what is returned by
/usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"

Answer (score 6):

Using MySQL Workbench it will be shown under "Server Status":
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found this really useful:

1. Find the MySQL process in Services under `Control Panel -> Administration Tools`
2. Right mouse click and choose `Properties`
3. Click and select the `Path to executable` and see if it contains the path to the `my.ini/my.cfg`

Comment: This worked for me on my Server 2008 install, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some servers have multiple MySQL versions installed and configured. Make sure you are dealing with the correct version running with a Unix
command of:

```
ps -ax | grep mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

For people running windows server with mysql as a service, an easy way to find out what config file you are running is to open up the services control panel, find your mysql service (in my case 'MYSQL56'), right click and click properties. Then from here you can check the "Path to Executable" which should have a `defaults-file` switch which points to where your config file is.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are running **mac** this can be also achieved by:

```
sudo dtruss mysqld 2>&1 | grep cnf
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed mysql use `brew install mysql`

```
mysqld --verbose --help | less
```

And it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you can use Sysinternals [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Open it and configure filter setting like this, then click "Add". Now procmon will monitor mysqld.

[image]

Now start your mysql server as normal. Procmon will capture mysql's background operations. Search "my." in the procmon result pane and you will find something like the following:

[image]

It's clear that mysql searches a list of configuration files in turn. In my case it found `C:\mysql-5.7.19-winx64\my.cnf` successfully so it's using this one.

Comment: This is basically the equivalent of the top answer, for windows.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're getting the correct files, especially if you have multiple versions of MySQL installed, for example, using tools like DBNgin.

This is what I did to find the correct file on Max (should work with Linux too):

Run `ps ax|grep mysqld` to list the running daemons:

```
36245   ??  S     18:46.08 /Users/Shared/DBngin/mysql/8.0.33/bin/mysqld --socket=/tmp/mysql_3306.sock
```

1: Check if `--no-defaults`, `--defaults-file` or `--defaults-extra-file` exists there.

2: Check the default locations:

```
/Users/Shared/DBngin/mysql/8.0.33/bin/mysqld -v --help|more
```

[image]

3: Also make sure that defaults are not overridden

```
/Users/Shared/DBngin/mysql/8.0.33/bin/mysqld --print-defaults
```

See also the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html).

Answer (score -1):

On CentOS and MariaDB you will find the MariaDB Server configuration settings in:
/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf

Comment: I do not even have that path...my.cnf.d

And yes, it is MariaDB...