# Is there a way to determine what configuration file MySQL is using?

Tags: mysql

Is there a command I can run within MySQL to determine where/which configuration file MySQL is using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/mysql-how-to-determine-which-config-file-is-being-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ver 5.0, no. But look at [Determine which configuration file is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/mysql-how-to-determine-which-config-file-is-being-used) for how to look from *outside* MySQL.