# Mysql query log not working

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the mysql query-log.

I searched the used my.cnf with https://stackoverflow.com/a/2896718/1012683 and added the line log=/var/log/mysqld_query.log to my.cnf. Then I restartet mysql but there is still no query-log.

Whats wrong here?

Thanks, Flo

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set `general_log`  to 'ON'. see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

Add this in `my.cnf` and then restart MySQL server:

```
general_log = 1
log=/var/log/mysqld_query.log
```

or

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Comment: it works! i've done SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON' and SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/var/log/mysqld_query.log'

Comment: where is my my.cnf? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether the general_log is 'ON' or 'OFF' first using query:

```
mysql>show variables like '%log%';
```

if the general_log is 'OFF', then the setting of log=... will not work. The general_log can be turn on when mysql is running (do not need to restart mysql) using cmd below:

```
mysql>SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

And the log file in variable general_log_file will be auto generated.