# Why are ~/.my.cnf variables not being honored?

Tags: mysql

I followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2896718/292408) to see which configuration files MySQL looks for, here is the output.

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

I then made a ~/.my.cnf file as it suggested and put `max_allowed_packet = 64M` in there in the group `mysqld`. When I restart and do a `mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';` it still has the value from the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and not my new overridden one. I did verify that MySQL is looking by running `strace mysql` and it does a stat() and then open() on ~/.my.cnf but the variable never overrides.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `~/.my.cnf` is a valid configuration source on your system? Please run `mysql --verbose --help` and post the appropriate section in your question. You can get more info on that in the question that you've linked.

Comment: Yup, Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

I updated the question with this info.

Comment: Check the perms to the file. Make sure all dirs and file itself is readable.

Comment: It is readable by ugo (664). Also, if I throw garbage in it then mysql will fail to start so it does appear to be scanning it.

Comment: @MikePurcell I think you are on to something. I was running strace mysql and it had no issues with open(). But when I run strace mysqld it gives a permission denied after open(). Not sure why though. I chmod 777'd it but it doesn't appear to be working yet. I am guessing it may need to be root as the owner?

Comment: Are you running selinux? Be sure /home has 755, /home/<user> has 755 and finally the file has 644 (or 664).

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 13.04. ~ is 755 and ~/.my.cnf is now 644. Did a sudo restart mysql but not yet successful.

Comment: run `sestatus` from cli. If it's 0 then none selinux issue, if it's 1, you either have to disable selinux (not recommended) or add a custom policy to allow the mysql user access to the home directory.

Comment: sestatus is currently not installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48109/discussion-between-elijah-lynn-and-mike-purcell)

Comment: Also for the record it should be `my.cnf`, not `.my.cnf`

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Not yet actually. According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html it is ~/.my.cnf