# Set mysql skip-networking to off

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying to setup my Ubuntu 12.10 server to accept remote mysql connections, however I am having difficulties setting skip-networking to off. Note I have already set the bind-address to the internet facing IP, instead of 127.0.0.1.

When I look in /etc/mysql/my.conf, the line "skip-networking" doesn't exist, however when I "mysql -p -u root" and then "SHOW VARIABLES;" "skip-networking" is "ON". I have added it as "#skip-networking" and restarted mysql service too.

I have looked to see if there are any stray my.conf files around in my home folder and /etc/ to no luck.

I am using mysql 5.5.

Anyone got any ideas how else I can set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) chapter for some tips on how to find the settings file. Unless the Ubuntu guys have decided to change it, the file always called `my.cnf` on Linux, never `my.conf`.

Additionally, lines that start with `#` are *comments*:

> `#`comment, `;`comment
>
> Comment lines start with “#” or “;”. A “#” comment can start in the
>   middle of a line as well.

... thus you need to remove the leading `#`; otherwise, the line is ignored.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, I've looked in all files listed, /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf,
/etc/mysql/my.cnf,
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf. Also I am purposely commenting, because i dont want the parameter to work. Still this is not updating in mysql variables when the service is restarted.

Comment: That really wasn't very helpful. He said he had commented it out, and the page you referred him to had nothing about "skip_networking" on it. It seems to be something that is "helpfully" compiled-in, and it's difficult to correct. Putting "skip_networking=OFF" or "skip_networking=0" in my.cnf doesn't seem to change it.

Comment: @JanSteinman I'm sorry my tips didn't solve your problem but please read answers in the context of Dimitri's question: how to use a MySQL settings file. I didn't add further clarifications because he accepted the answer, thus assumed the doubt was solved.

Answer (score 4):

Put "--skip_networking=0" on the mysql command line.

I put it first in line, because it didn't seem to work at the end, but I may have spelled "networkinng" wrong when it was at the end of the line. :-)

It helps to look at your logs. Mine said "150213 17:57:10 [ERROR] /opt/local/lib/mariadb-10.1/bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'skip_networkinng=0'" I had also tried 'skip_networking=OFF', which it didn't like, either.

I don't know where you start it up in Ubuntu, but on Mac OS, you need to have the following in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mysql.mysqld (in part, look at other LaunchDaemons to see the rest):

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/local/lib/mariadb-10.1/bin/mysqld</string>
        <string>--skip_networking=0</string>
        <string>--socket=/opt/local/var/run/mariadb-10.1/mysqld.sock</string>
        <string>--user=mysql</string>
        <string>--port=3306</string>
        <string>--datadir=/opt/local/var/db/mariadb-10.1</string>
        <string>--pid-file=/opt/local/var/run/mariadb-10.1/dns.local.pid</string>
    </array>
```

(obviously you need to substitute your paths and such...)

I'm pretty sure this solves your problem! Please up-vote me and mark me as the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can determine which config file is being used via one of the methods described in [Determine which configuration file is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/mysql-how-to-determine-which-config-file-is-being-used).

A few more suggestions:

- Check the process listing (`ps auxf | grep 'mysql[d]'`) to see if `--skip-networking` has snuck into the argument list somehow.
- See if mysqld or any other process is listening on 3306 (assuming the default port): `netstat -lnp46 | grep -w 3306`
- Double-check the ip address you are binding to, and try to connect locally to the ip address you are binding to.
- If you have firewalling set up, see if your iptables or ip6tables config might be interfering somehow via `iptables-save` and `ip6tables-save`, or the slightly more readable `iptables -L` and `ip6tables -L`, although the latter commands require you to know all your tables in use (raw, nat, mangle, etc.).

Comment: @VivekVardhan if you mean that `--skip-networking` is in your ps listing, check if `skip-networking=1` (or [`ON` or `TRUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-modifiers.html)) is in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, or in files included therefrom.  Also check `skip_networking`, as this is an alternate name for the same setting.  So (assuming a vanilla Ubuntu 12.10 mysql setup): `grep -ire skip.networking' /etc/mysql`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the similar error.
I found mysqld_safe is running.
I have tried 'kill {PID}', but it doesn't work. (mysqld_safe would restart with different PID).
Finally, I found `pkill mysqld` do the work, and it won't hurt your running mysqld service.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, for ubuntu 18.04 & mysql 5.7, It was not in file 'my.cnf', but by running below command

```
sudo grep -rnw '/etc/' -e 'skip-networking'
```

I found it in file `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf.`

Comment: you hit my point man~

I followed you and run this "systemctl daemon-reload".

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.04.2, you can find this settings in

> /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf

there will be a **ExecStart** key and its have multiple configurations.
Here you can provide **--skip-networking** as **OFF**

```
--skip-networking=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code !!**

Go to Directory

```
/etc/mysql
```

open file my.cnf by

```
sudo nano my.cnf
```

or

```
vi my.cnf
```

Now comment below lines

```
#skip-networking=0
#skip-bind-address
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Stop your MySQL server. and then run this command.

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip_networking=0
```

and close the terminal window and re-open it.