# How to configure my.cnf in 5.6.17?

Tags: mysql, linux, my.cnf, mysql-5.6, system-variable

On production server(linux machine mysql 5.6.17), I tried to find my.cnf to change the system variables, but my.cnf was not in /etc/my.cnf location. It was in usr/ directory. Also that file contains only comments like -

```
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
```

Please tell me where should I copy my.cnf and how I can change variables like -

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200M
max_connections = 300
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways you can modify global variables like that.

#### In your my.cnf file

Add/edit the values under the `[mysqld]` block, so;

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200M
max_connections = 300
```

Then restart the `mysqld` daemon for changes to take affect.

#### Running a query

You can run the following queries to change the values for those variables, but there will be reset to default once `mysqld` daemon restarts/server is rebooted/etc.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200M;
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 300;
```

You can read more about that here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html

Comment: @hd, but in my.cnf everything is commented by #. After adding innodb_buffer_pool_size and max_connections, what will happen to other parameters? Will they remain same(default value)? Or I have to add all?

Comment: They should remain as default. I run it within a development environment beforehand, as I've not had *that* much experience with altering global variables.

Comment: ok and what about location? should I copy my.cnf from /usr to etc/ ?

Comment: @Aamir see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-config-file-is-being-used

Comment: link is related to mysql 5.0. I am working on 5.6, thats why I am getting trouble for my.cnf setup, any help would be greatly appreciated.