# Codeigniter Database Error 1055 - isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->group_by('hs_tktno');
$query = $this->db->where('hs_toid', $id);
$query = $this->db->order_by('hs_id', "desc");
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$data["list"] =  $query->result();
```

Im Getting the following error when i try to excute the above code
any ideas?

> Error Number: 1055
>
> 'dbname.table.hs_id' isn't in GROUP BY
>
> SELECT * FROM (`table`) WHERE `hs_status` = '0' GROUP BY `hs_tktno`

Comment: use  $query = $this->db->group_by('hs_tktno'); after $query = $this->db->where('hs_toid', $id);

Comment: write where clause first then you write group by $query = $this->db->where('hs_toid', $id); $query = $this->db->group_by('hs_tktno');

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understood much by question, but your query written is wrong. It should be like this,

```
$this->db->group_by('hs_tktno');
$this->db->where('hs_toid', $id);
$this->db->order_by('hs_id', "desc");
$query = $this->db->get('table');

return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, the solution that I found was to change your my.cnf or my-default.cnf in your server. For my case, I am using mac, this file can be found at /usr/local/mysql/support-files/

Steps to produce solution:

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd /usr/local/mysql/support-files/`
3. `sudo vim my.cnf`
4. scroll all the way to the bottom and press i to insert
5. replace the existing slq_mode with `sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
6. press esc to exit input mode
7. type `:wq` to save and close vim
8. now restart your mysql with `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart` or `sudo service mysql restart`
9. All done and you are set to enjoy your coding. Have fun :)

For some who couldn't find their my.cnf file. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-configuration-file-is-being-used) for Mark B answer. This will help you to find  your my.cnf .

If you only have my-default.cnf, you could just copy it to ~/.my.cnf with the command `sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf ~/.my.cnf` and remember to restart after that.