# Appropriate location of my.ini file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Where should I find `my.ini`?

System Profile says `%ProgramFiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini` This seems strange, though, since I work with MySQL 6.3. Is that correct?

Comment: How do i do that, just write phpinfo() into a empty query? because it dosen´t recognise phpinfo()

Comment: why not search for it on the computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-config-file-is-being-used

Comment: MySQL 6.3? That's not right. MySQL server != MySQL Workbench. Your current system assumes MySQL server 5.0, so how about simply using your actual MySQL server location (which, might be 5.5 or 5.6 or somewhere else).