# Where is the configuration file of MySQL Server on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: mysql, configuration-files, osx-yosemite

I have been reading a lot about where the configuration file of MySQL Server should be on OS X Yosemite and:

- Exist a lot of criteria about that, but I didn't found a kind of *standard place* to put the configuration file. I mean, I can't determine the place that most people put it or what is the same, the place where OS X Yosemite guys or MySQL guys recommend put it.
- The MySQL 5.5.45 official installer appear not set any configuration file at all, is that true or I'm missing something?

Anybody with experience developing on Yosemite can bring me to the light?

**EDIT:**

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/mysql/
total 344
drwxr-xr-x  16 root    wheel      544 Jul  8 04:26 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    wheel      170 Aug  9 11:20 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel    17987 Jul  8 03:53 COPYING
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel   150701 Jul  8 03:53 INSTALL-BINARY
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel     2496 Jul  8 03:53 README
drwxr-xr-x  46 root    wheel     1564 Jul  8 04:26 bin
drwxr-xr-x  13 _mysql  _mysql     442 Aug 13 15:22 data
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    wheel      170 Jul  8 04:26 docs
drwxr-xr-x  37 root    wheel     1258 Jul  8 04:26 include
drwxr-xr-x  12 root    wheel      408 Aug  9 11:20 lib
drwxr-xr-x   4 root    wheel      136 Jul  8 04:26 man
drwxr-xr-x  19 root    wheel      646 Aug  9 11:20 mysql-test
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel      102 Jul  8 04:26 scripts
drwxr-xr-x  32 root    wheel     1088 Jul  8 04:26 share
drwxr-xr-x  28 root    wheel      952 Jul  8 04:26 sql-bench
drwxr-xr-x  16 root    wheel      544 Jul  8 04:26 support-files
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-config-file-is-being-used) contains a useful comment in the accepted answer (last comment).

Answer (score 1):

It should be in `/usr/local/mysql`.