# how to change port number in MySQL Server 5.6 on windows( Not in XAMPP inbuilt mysql)

Tags: mysql

1. I stopped the MySQL Service in Windows from TaskManager Option.
2. And then, I opend and Choosed the port number  in "my-default.ini". like following (C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my-default.ini)

[mysqld]
port = 33062

3. Saved It.
4. Then I stated the service 'MySql' from the 'TaskManager'.
5. I checked the port number from 'mysql command' prompt. but port number is not changed to 33062. Instead of that default port number is there in the 'my.ini' file.
   Please show the way to change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine which configuration file is being used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-configuration-file-is-being-used)

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The link provided by you won't suit's to me.

Comment: Why not? You are probably editing the wrong config file. That topic helps you to locate it.

Answer (score 9):

Steps to change the port number for MySQL Server 5.7 :

1. Stop the MySQL service from `services.msc`(To open `services.msc` go to run command and then type `services.msc`)
2. Go to the location `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7` (ProgramData is a hidden folder. So you need to enable the hidden items from Folder Options).
3. In the `MySQL Server 5.7` folder you will find `my.ini` file.
4. Open `my.ini` file and search for `port`.
5. Give your desired port number (like port=3632).
6. Save and exit `my.ini` file.(if it brings a file owner error, the quickest hack is to rename the file, edit it accordingly and then save the file as 'my.ini'. You can then proceed to delete the first renamed file.)
7. Then stat the service from the `services.msc`.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the following simple steps

1. Rerun the installer by going to **start > MySQL > MySQL Community Installer**
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/s78DN.png
2. Click on **Reconfigure** next to **MySQL Server**
3. Click and **Next**
4. Now change the port numbers to maybe 3309

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs5Vu.png
5. Click **Next** change the password, test it and that ends it