# MySQL - PhpMyAdmin Replication Reset Master Configuration to retrieve server-id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, replication, database-replication, master-slave

MySQL server + phpmyadmin

On the replication tab, it looks like someone already configured the master replication:

[image]

However, I do not see the following lines in `my.cnf`, which should have been added at the time the master was configured :

```
server-id=*****
log-bin=******
log-error=*****
```

How do I retrieve those values? Or how do I reset the master configuration so that I can perform the whole process myself (I also want to select/ignore new databases)?

Comment: from command line inside mysql `SHOW MASTER STATUS \G;` ? I never did but I think you can execute this query in phpMyadmin if your user has the permissions

Comment: `SHOW MASTER STATUS` (without \G that is not working) displays 5 things: File, Position that have values; and Binlog_Do_DB, Binlog_Ignore_DB and Executed_Gtid_Set that are empty.

Comment: You should have also the database that is replicated in `Binlog_Do_DB: db_name`

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-configuration-file-is-being-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my issue.

**Note:** The `server-id` is just a unique identifier that you can chose.

I had to enter those lines in the **master's** `my.cnf` file:

```
#master my.cnf
server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=database1
binlog_do_db=database2
binlog_do_db=database3
binlog_do_db=database4
binlog_do_db=database5
```

And those lines in the **slave's** `my.cnf` file:

```
#slave my.cnf
server-id = 2
replicate-do-db=database1
replicate-do-db=database2
replicate-do-db=database3
replicate-do-db=database4
replicate-do-db=database5
```

Then on the slave server's phpmyadmin go to replication tab and click `Stop SQL Thread only` and `Stop IO Thread only`