# Too many open files when importing data from schema (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, macos

I am trying to import a SQL file, that has about 5.5 GB of data, into one of my local schemas on my Macbook machine. I keep getting the following error in mysql which prevents the import from finishing:

```
errno: 24 - Too many open files)
```

I created a `my.cnf` file and placed it in the following directory `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.25/my.cnf`. The `my.cnf` file has the following set

```
open_files_limit = 100000
```

however, when I run the following query I still have the `open_files_limit` set to 256:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%';
```

I am not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might by the value `100000`  too big for this config

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit

Answer (score 0):

1. check if you conf file is used by mysql.

[Location of my.cnf file on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos)

[Determine which MySQL configuration file is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-mysql-configuration-file-is-being-used)

2. On Unix, the value of open_files_limit cannot be set greater than ulimit -n.

Comment: thanks! I will upvote as soon as I get enough reputation to upvote