# How to fix "unknown variable 'nnodb_buffer_pool_size" if mysql is down/failed?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The Mariabd service failed and in the log is this error:
/usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'nnodb_buffer_pool_size=2450'

I don't know why with the "i" at the beginning

In the My.cnf file I didn't have the instruction:
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2450

I put it there under [mysqld] and also [mysqld_safe], remove the ib_logfile and restart the server and continue the error: Failed to start MariaDB database server. and in the log /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'nnodb_buffer_pool_size=2450'

I'm not an expert and at this point I dont know else what can I do.

Could anyone please help to understand what is wrong and how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Multiple "my.cnf" files are searched; perhaps it is in another one.  (And 2450 would be disastrously tiny.)

Comment: I search my.cnf file like this: "find / -name my.cnf"
and the only result was this: /etc/my.cnf
Before the error I didnt have the variable: "innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2450 " and now there is: innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G

Comment: Try something like [Determine which MySQL configuration file is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/580331)