# SQL_MODE error keeps coming back even after using SET sql_mode

Tags: mysql

My back is giving me the usual:

> ...not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I'm using mysql as a container, and I tried `set sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` in all databases, for all users... And the error remains the same... Don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

And fix the problem temporary , but  after `MySQL` restart the default settings will come back.

You need to set on your `.cnf` file below line and restart the `MySQL` server.
Default options are read from the following files in the given order: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf  .

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

I suggest better fix the queries rather than removing `only_full_group_by`

Comment: I can't find the  /etc/my.cnf and /usr/local/etc/my.cnf files... I was able to change only the /etc/mysql/my.cnf... And it's not working on restart, is there anything I need to do?

Comment: @RafaelPáduaDelCorona what is your mysql version. Maybe you have different path of my.cnf. Check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-mysql-configuration-file-is-being-used to find the configuration file